# Why is this Swiper onReachEnd callback firing twice in Ionic Slides?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, swiper.js

Why is this [Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper) `onReachEnd` callback being executed twice?

I am using [Ionic Slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/), and my stack has 3 pages: the root page, a primary slides page, and a secondary slides page. The secondary slides page should close when I reach the end:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app/secondary-slides.html'
})
export class SecondarySlidesPage {
  sliderOptions = {
    onReachEnd: () => { this.nav.pop(); },
  };

  constructor(private nav: NavController) { }
}
```

The above works, except that the `onReachEnd` callback is called twice, so *two* pages are popped off the stack, closing the secondary slides page *and* the primary slides page, taking my back to the root page. The primary slides page looks like this:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app/slides.html'
})
export class SlidesPage {
  sliderOptions = { };

  constructor(private nav: NavController) { }

  public secondarySlides() {
   this.nav.push(SecondarySlidesPage); 
  }
}
```

Here's a [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/PUI77NBep2sxO0aCcsdg/) demonstrating the issue.

How can I avoid popping both pages? If this is a bug, is it in Ionic or in Swiper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I can unset the callback after its first use.

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app/secondary-slides.html'
})
export class SecondarySlidesPage {
  @ViewChild('slides') slides:Slides;

  sliderOptions = {
    onReachEnd: () => {
      this.slides.slider.params.onReachEnd = undefined;
      this.nav.pop();
    },
  };

  constructor(private nav: NavController) { }
}
```

What's happening is that when the secondary slides page is removed, the individual slide components are destroyed. This automatically updates the `slider` object, which is now at a new end slide and fires the callback again. I modified the Ionic slides to remove the `rapidUpdate` call in `Slide.ngOnDestroy`, and the issues goes away.

I didn't expect to figure something out so quickly after finally deciding to post a question. [Bug report here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/9768).

Answer (score 0):

this answer could help someone else

What I did inside the `ionSlideReachEnd` function, was ask for the var what is inside the for-loop, if it is undefined then return false, and this is the way how the function didn't fire twice at the beginning

Example:

```
<ion-slides (ionSlideReachEnd)="exampleSlideEnd()">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let sl of slides">
```

And in your .ts controller

```
exampleSlideEnd(){

  if( this.slides == undefined) return false;
  this.callOtherFunction();
}
```